# Checking that a point is in a spherical polygon

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-geometry

I am trying to find an algorithm to check if a point $p$ on the surface of a sphere lies within a spherical polygon with vertices at $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_J$. Any polygons I am considering will be "small", so the smaller of the two potential polygons on the surface of the sphere. I also expect my polygons to be spherical squares and hexagons, that is nothing too irregular. My points are arranged so that any polygon will be CCW.

Right now, I am thinking of using the following. I have not yet found a counter-example to suggest it shouldn't work, but given how hard it has been to find such an algorithm I am wondering if I am missing something as this seems very straighforward.

If $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_{j,p}$ is unit vector normal to the great circle connecting $v_j$ and $p$, then the interior angle for the points $v_j$-$p$-$v_{j+1}$ will be $$\alpha_j = \arccos(\hat{\mathbf{n}}_{j,p}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}_{p,j+1})$$
and the point is in the polygon iff
$$\sum_{j=1}^J\alpha_j=2\pi.$$

Can anyone suggest a reason why this would not work? If one checked that angles were CW or CCW, is there any reason it could not be extended for more complex polygons with more of a "Pacman" shape? (Apologies for poor vernacular!)

Comment: if each polygon is convex and within a hemisphere, the interior of a polygon is given by being within every edge that defines it, and in the correct hemisphere. Each gret circle edge is given by the 3-D equation $ax+by+cz = 0,$  and one side is given by the appropriate one from $ax+by+cz \geq 0,$ or the opposite. Done properly, a polygon has all inequalities true, and the interior of the diametrically opposite polygon is given by negating each condition.

Comment: Alright, for non-convex pacman shapes, you could subdivide each polygon into a few convex shapes; triangles are guaranteed to work. So these polygons would be a list of triangles.

Comment: Given a $p$ located inside a polygon $\{v_i\}$ according to your algorithm, what does the algorithm output for $p'$ antipodal to $p$ on the sphere?

Comment: @user3733558, the output is "False", which is a good thing...

Comment: Thanks @Will Jagy, what you propose in your first comment appears more efficient computationally and I will have to do this calculation many times. Treating the location of the point as a vector with the centre of the sphere at the origin, I think the sign of $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot\vec{p}$ should tell me which side of the plane it is on (or if it is on the great circle).

Comment: @ramzikai That was the only "worry" with your plan, but since you're re-implementing with Will's idea, I guess the point is moot anyway :)

Comment: Triangulate the polygon and for each spherical triangle do an inside/outside test between its non-spherical counterpart and the projected point on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestions in Will's comments, if a $J$-sided polygon is convex and CCW, then $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_j$ points into the polygon and so for a point $\mathbf{p}$ if $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_j\cdot\mathbf{p}>0\,\forall j\in J$ then the point is in the polygon. Should the $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_j\cdot\mathbf{p}=0$ for any side $j$ then the point lies on that line.

Comment: What is $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_j$ here? Is it the normal vector of the great-circle plane between $v_i$ and $v_{i + 1}$?

Comment: @shadowtalker, yes - also it needs to be defined so it is pointing "into" the polygon.